# 'at' or not? - Should I use 'at' in that sentence?

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following sentences is correct, or perhaps both? And why?

> Standard check-in time is 3 pm.
>
> Standard check-in time is **at** 3 pm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A time is simply expressed as 3pm, 15:00, etc: check in time is 3pm, dinner time is 13:00, etc, but an event happens **at** a time: we check in at 3pm, we shall dine at 13:00.

Comment: I get it, thanks. Does that mean that using 'at' ('Standard check-in time is at 3 pm') would be considered incorrect or just "inferior"/less common'?

Comment: Not incorrect, just slightly less common.